# Stargazer tables: Latex math symbols in One Column

Tags: r, latex, stargazer

I am trying to use Stargazer to generate a simple table of a data.frame. The first column has some math symbols but stargazer is not reading it properly.
I did the following:

```
df_results <- data.frame('Variable' = c("$\\beta_{0}$"),
                         'Posterior Mean' =1,
                         'Posterior St. Dev.'=1,
                         check.names=FALSE)

stargazer(df_results,summary = F,table.placement = 'H')
```

And I got this result:

```
\begin{table}[H] \centering 
  \caption{} 
  \label{} 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} cccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & Variable & Posterior Mean & Posterior St. Dev. \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
1 & \$\textbackslash beta\_\{0\}\$ & $1$ & $1$ \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

How do I remove the backslash?

Answer (score 0):

How about using `xtable`?

````
---
title: "math symbols in summary"
author: "author"
date: "2023-01-12"
output:
  pdf_document: default
  html_document: default
subtitle: xtable
---

## data

```{r}
df_results <- data.frame('Variable' = c("$\\beta_{0}$"),
                         'Posterior Mean' =1,
                         'Posterior St. Dev.'=1,
                         check.names=FALSE)
```

## print 

```{r results='asis'}
library(xtable)
print(xtable(df_results),sanitize.text.function=function(x){x})
```
````

[image]